# Duplicate Boolean fields in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have boolean field as

```
private boolean isCustom;
```

having getter and setters as

```
public boolean isCustom() {
        return isCustom;
    }
public void setCustom(boolean isCustom) {
        this.isCustom = isCustom;
    }
```

And in this case my JSON will be `{"custom":false}`

but i want JSON to be `{"isCustom":false}`

so I added *@JsonProperty* :

```
@JsonProperty
    private boolean isCustom;
```

But now there is another problem as my JSON is **`{"isCustom":false,"custom":false}`**

**Q : How can i eliminate unwanted/duplicate field in this case ?**

Note: I am using ***jackson-all-1.9.11.jar***

Comment: You should be able to just put `@JsonProperty(name="isCustom")` above the boolean declaration instead. Also, you should rename the field to `custom`. That may be causing the double-variable.

Comment: i need property to be "isCustom"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The annotation accepts a parameter. And it should be placed on the field, getter, **and** setter to prevent the duplicate

```
@JsonProperty("isCustom")
```

Comment: this works.. but any simple solution (i am having lots of boolean values) ? and why jackson generated two fields ?

Comment: It makes the fields based upon the names of the getters and field names. If they differ, you get duplicates. Only way around that is the annotation. If you don't want to do it manually, then generate your classes from here.  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: even if I add @JsonProperty("isCustom") only on getter it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can set custom name in json property like this

```
@JsonProperty(name="isCustom")
private boolean isCustom;
```

Please refer [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@JsonProperty("isCustom")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonProperty(value = "isCustom")`annotation

Comment: Please add further explanation about your answer

Answer (score 0):

Put this annotation `(@JsonProperty("isCustom"))` over getter and setter, it will map only one field and vanish duplicates (for primitive Boolean).

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do it:

- Add `@JsonProperty("isCustom")` to your property
- rename the property to `custom` (this will remove `isCustom` from the json)

Comment: i need property to be "isCustom"

Comment: Okay, in that case, we can go ahead with first option.